# Shipment comment add event observer mangento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to send sms on shipment comment add. is their any observer for knowing comment has been added to the shipment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `controller_action_postdispatch_Frontroute_Controller_Action`

and you can achieve your requirement.

I guess there no any another particular event on that action.